# Bootstrap 4 custom form with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 introduces [custom forms](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1) to customize checkboxes and radio buttons. Here is a way to generate the following templates with Simple Form?

**Checkbox:**

```
<label class="c-input c-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  Check this custom checkbox
</label>
```

**Radio:**

```
<label class="c-input c-radio">
  <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  Toggle this custom radio
</label>
<label class="c-input c-radio">
  <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  Or toggle this other custom radio
</label>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So just replace the `input` with simple forms element?

Comment: Il don't know how to generate the `<span class="c-indicator"></span>`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `input` with `form` element:

```
<%= simple_form_for :foo do |f| %>

  <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
    <%= f.check_box :bar %>

    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
    Check this custom checkbox
  </label>

<% end %>
```

Which will generate:

```
<label class="c-input c-checkbox">
  <input name="foo[bar]" type="hidden" value="0">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo[bar]" id="foo_bar">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  Check this custom checkbox
</label>
```

Check the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ornvH0UmrG).

Same goes for your second example, just replace the elements with RoR's form elements.